# Why is promise.all returning an array within an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

I am coding on the backend (node & express) to make a request to the database (mongodb using mongoose)

When I run this code:

```
let RefundRequests = req.body.refundRequests.map(e => {return (

    Ticket.findById(e)

    )}  )

Promise.all(RefundRequests).then(data => {console.log('data', data) })
```

the console logs an array with an object:

```
    data [
     {
      //relevant data
     }
    ]
```

but when I change the promise to:

```
let RefundRequests = req.body.refundRequests.map(e => {return (

        Ticket.find({
                _id: e,
                refunded: false
            })
        )})
```

the same promise.all logs an array containing an array that contains an object:

```
data [
  [
    {
     //relevant data
    }
  ]
]
```

Why is there a difference? I would prefer if it returned one array with an object for ease of coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find returns an array of documents, findById returns a single document.
[finding documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html)